# Return text string for highest duplicate values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, google-spreadsheets

I've been battling with a **google sheets** conundrum so hoping someone can help.

In a nutshell, I'm trying to achieve the following based on the image below:

- Where the name is the same in column C
- Return 'winner', 'tied' or 'loser' in column F based on the respective value in column D.

  - Highest single value in D = 'winner'
  - Two or more identical highest values in D = 'tied'
  - Any value that is not the highest in D = 'loser'

[image]

I currently have it working with a helper column that uses a combination of ArrayFormula, IF and the MAX functions that returns the text 'winner' and 'loser' in column F.

But this falls over when I try to introduce a 'tied' result to column G.

I've tried using Google Sheet's `QUERY` function, but to no avail.

Here's an open sheet to have a play around with if anyone has any ideas:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FDEja_QIGUIWcFpbZ8-FtPquBCUCkq3TLIHG2TT1OMI/edit?usp=sharing

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: please choose an app.  This will be done very differently in google sheet than MS Excel.

Comment: Hi @Jimmy ,, what I've realized that you on write track only you need to modify the formula in F2,, should be `=IF(A2="","",IF(E2=D2,"Tied",IF(E2>D2,"winner","loser"))) ` ,, hope this work for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Using Helper data the issue can be fixed.*

**:Caveat:**

- Below shown method works with Google Sheet as well Excel.
- This method considers MAXIMUM value for Kilman is 2.8 and for Kelchi is 3.9.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell H2 finds RANK:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",SUMPRODUCT(--(F2=$F$2:$F$7),(--(G2<$G$2:$G$7)))+1)
  ```
- Final formula in cell I2:

  ```
   =IFERROR(IF(AND($F$2:$F$7=F2,H2=1),"Tied",IF(AND($F$2:$F$7=F2,H2>3),"Looser","Winner")),"")
  ```

**N.B.**

- For Kilman G2 & G4 are TIED, since his Max value is 2.8 .
- G3 is WINNER since is less than the Max (2.8) and higher than the lowest (2.3).
- And, for Kelchi WINNER is G6 since is less than his max 3.9.
- `H2>3` in the formula in cell I2 is
  Eitable/Adjustable since the lowest RANK is 4.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi @Jimmy ,, please check my post I do believe that I've solved the problem,, in case you find any further issue do reply through comments, also if find it's working, then you may mark is as [Answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well up vote.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh sorry it's taken me ages to get back to this. This is great! A rank helper column is a great solution. The only bit that isn't correct is the formula in I2. Which is kind of where I was stuck before. So based on your approach using the rank column, I2 should hold:

Comment: - If rank = 1 and *no other helper cell* within the range of Kilman (C2:C5) also has the rank of 1, declare "Winner"

- If rank = 1 and *one or more helper cells* within the range of Kilman (C2:C5) also has the rank of 1, declare "Tied"

- If rank = >2 , declare "Loser"

Comment: Looking at your example, I think what's missing is a third logical expression in the AND statement that gets the range of Kilman's respective ranks in column H (so H2:H5), and runs a countif that says – IF rank 1 appears more than once return True, if not False. So something like: `IF(COUNTIF(H2:H5,"=1")>1,True,False)` but i can't define the range like that as it needs to be defined by column F.

Comment: @Jimmy,, for Rank  the best possible I've used is been applied,, since while Ranking,, duplicates are possible like 2.8 for Killman so both are no 1!! COUNTIF doesn't work properly,,, in N.B. part I've explained the logic,, now in case you solve the issue then please post it as answer,, help me others too !!

Comment: Plzz write your concern that why this has been down voted !!

Comment: That wasn't me Rajesh! I found your answer very helpful. Just upvoted your answer.

Comment: Glad to help you @Jimmy,, please keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

As `Scott Craner`says, which version? Which program even? Well, I'll forge forth...

Use something like the following. The approach is valid and can be adapted to version and/or program. And while I will use today's Excel, each thing done has older ways of doing it that you can adapt each bit for.

Use:  (no need for a helper column, just insert where the final answer is desired)

```
=LET(  MaxBid,  MAX(FILTER($D$2:$D$7,$C$2:$C$7=C2)),    NameBid,  FILTER($D$2:$D$7,$C$2:$C$7=C2),
       IF(D2<>MaxBid,  "Loser",  IF(COUNTA(NameBid)>1,  "Tied",  "Winner"  )  ))
```

(Obviously, adjust cell references to fit the real ranges.)

The basic approach is to first isolate on each name in the list, so you have an output for every line, but to use `MAX()` to find the highest bid value for each name, whatever it might be, and in the form of an internal array that the formula makes use of. Once you have the high bid for each  name, each line's name is tested for win, tie, or lose vs. that MaxBid that the name has. If the bid for that line is not the MaxBid value, it is by definition a loser and the oouter `IF()` outputs that. If it DID match the highest bid, the inner `IF()` tests to see if more than one occurrence of the MaxBid exists. If so, it outputs "Tied" and if there are NOT more than one occurrences, it outputs "Winner" which covers all the possible ways for it to play out.

If you cannot use `LET()` (you don't have it, or perhaps it's users who may not have it, just replace the names it uses with the formula pieces it is given for their outputs. If you don't have `FILTER()`, you can easily replace it as there are several "old" ways of doing its work. If you don't ahve `SPILL` functionality, use {CSE} array entry instead. And if you only have Google, not Excel, it's probably even easier to substitute techniques.

If one knew what your program situation really were, there'd be a LOT mor eincentive to just provide a finished formula instead of "edit this and paste that" vagueness. Ah well.

Comment: Hi @Jeorje – thanks for the detailed run down. To be honest, I thought on the whole Google Sheets and Excel used the same base set of formulas, hence why I thought it could be solved using either. So I'm actually using Google Sheets (not excel), so the LET formula you mentioned obviously isn't supported (now I see why I should have referenced which program). Would you be able to apply the above approach to the open google sheet I provided? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FDEja_QIGUIWcFpbZ8-FtPquBCUCkq3TLIHG2TT1OMI/edit?usp=sharing